# Javascript Regex AND

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get the whole line as a result,

when the line has 8 or more digits

AND

when there are more than 1 spaces between any digits per line.

But how can I check that with a regular expression? I already tried `/((?:\d{8,})(?:[.* ]{2,}))/g` but it doens' work. (Of course I also tried lots of other expressions)

This is the list to test:

```
yes:
123 456 789 0123
1 2345 678
123 123 123123
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

no (it has less than 2 spaces):
1231 23123123
no (it has less than 8 digits)
1 2345 67
```

I prepared this, here you can play =) [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oB1rU2/1)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Imho, this would be fairly easier with a simple split on space and then count what you need to count (spaces, numbers).

Comment: @BastiM, easier, but far less effective, as you'll do several passes on the data (one to get and one more to count) Regex compilers generate a one pass DFA or NFA that allows you to get a match in one pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
/^(?=.* .* )(\d *){8,}$/gm
```

- `^` Anchors the regex at the start of line
- `(?=.* .* )` Look ahead assertion. Checks if the line contains 2 spaces.
- `(\d *){8,}` matches `8` digits in the line
- `$` anchors regex at end

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/oB1rU2/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
/^(?=(.*?\d){8})(?=(\S* ){2}).+$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oB1rU2/2)

First lookahead is to make sure there are at least 8 digits and 2nd one is to make sure there are at least 2 spaces.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R and anubhava: thanks for your help, but in my regex it doesn't work. Can you tell me why? I have a very long regex, that almost works perfectly. Now I want to exclude the matches without white spaces and with less than 8 digits. So I added (?=(.*?\d){8,}) in front of my whole regex, but it also matches +33 (33) 3 if there are some more numbers following.
And the exclusion of numbers containing no white space doesn't work either (its not in my example regex). [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rS6qM7/1)

Comment: Well this answer is for the question you asked above and works with the example data shown in answer. I would suggest creating a new question with phone number problem and accept one of the working solutions here.

Comment: ah ok this is how it works =) Sorry I didn't know that. I will ask a new question. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

This is the most simple regex I found without lookahead and extended features of perl and friends.  Of course, digits can be abbreviated as \d and repetitions using {n1, n2} notation.

```
\([0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*\ .*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*[0-9].*\ .*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9]*[0-9].*\ .*\ .*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9][0-9]*\)
```

Sorry for the flood.  It recognizes every string with at least eight digits and at least two spaces on it.  It can have non numeric characterrs interspersed.  If you don't want them it can be arranged to not allow them. DFA is by far simpler than this.  So written, can be used as a search string in **vim(1)** and it will match from the leftmost digit to the rightmost in the line (not including extra spaces)